# Replicating column values to a new column

Tags: r

I have a data frame BLUP, with

```
Location  Value
  A          3
  B          5
  C          10
```

I want the output looking like

```
Location   Value1  Location2   Value2   Diff(Value2-Value1)
A             3        A          3          0
A             3        B          5          2
A             3        C          10         7
B             5        A          3         -2
B             5        B          5          0
B             5        C          10         5
C             10       A          3         -7
C             10       B          5         -5
C             10       C          10         0
```

I am not sure how to create this output table in R for a much larger data frame. Any suggestions would be appreciated as I am new to R.

Comment: What's the rationale for adding the new columns?

Comment: @NelsonGon To create an additional column "difference" where I can get differences between value 2 and value1, and later merge the data frame file to a distance matrix file for Location A,B,C. I dont know if I am complicating things or if there's an easier way..

Comment: To get the difference, wouldn't you need to have value2 in the data frame first?As your question stands you only have value 1 and there is no clear logic behind value 2.

Comment: @NelsonGon, I edited the question a bit, maybe it makes sense now? Thank you :)

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I only have Location1 and Value1 in my original dataframe. I am confused as how to create Location2 and Value 2 in the format in the above shown example.

Comment: You should have value2 somewhere or manual create it like so: `mutate(Value2=c(add your data))` If you already have it in another column simply use `?cbind()`

Comment: You could do this in 3 easy steps: `res <- expand.grid(BLUP) ; res[, c("Location2", "Value2")] <- BLUP ; res$Diff <- with(res, Value2 - Value)`. Then `res` is your new data set. Though `expand.grid` could be a bit costly.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Great, the first two steps were exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! The only small problem with the output is that in the output, I wanted the 'Location' values to be (A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C) and not (A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C). But I should be able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?
If you already have the first columns except the last, simply do

```
mutate(Diff=Value2-Value1)
```

Otherwise add columns using `mutate`. You can look at `?cbind` too

```
    #Location1 and Value1 should already be in your data. 


library(tidyverse)
        BLUP %>% 
          rename(Location2=Location1,Value2=Value1) %>% 

          mutate(Location1=rep("A",3),Value1=rep(3,3),Diff=Value2-Value1) %>% 
          select(contains("1"),everything())
```